# How to read span through aria-hidden?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webbot

I've been trying for about 2 hours now with no luck to see how to read text between a span that has an "aria-hidden=true" tag. The code for the site is like this:

```html
<div class="badge">
    <span aria-hidden="true">123</span>
</div>
```

Any idea how you can view the text with xpath or anything similar? My current code is this, but returns random span text from across the page for some reason.

```py
for i in web.find_elements(xpath="//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' badge ')]//span[1]"):
                    print(i.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you share the rest of the html or a link to it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the HTML you posted, I don't see the attribute `innerText` in the `span` element. To get the text of the element in Selenium, you should use `getText()`

```
for i in web.find_elements(xpath="//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' badge ')]//span[1]"):
                    print(i.getText())
```